# How to join multiple MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out retained users for our application using the login history we keep for every user.

I want to know users who registered in month 1, then came back in month 2, then also came back in month 3 and so on.....

A single query is simple:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT DISTINCT player_id 
FROM login_history 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')-1);
```

The above gives me unique logins for `January`, simple.

**Query 2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT player_id 
FROM login_history 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1);
```

The above now gives me the unique logins for `February`.

How can I join the two, or more, to give me the player_id's common to all results?

I have tried using IN statements but that is hugely slow..

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use `group by` and `having` instead of `distinct`:

```
SELECT player_id
FROM login_history
GROUP BY player_id
HAVING SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 and
       SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0;
```

For efficiency, you should still include the `where`:

```
SELECT player_id
FROM login_history
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1)
GROUP BY player_id
HAVING SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0 and
       SUM(timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1)) > 0;
```

Comment: This works well, with the exception that I need to add the registration_datetime as validation for the player_id's.

So, I only want to check player_id's where the registration_datetime is between two dates...

    select player_id from player where registration_datetime LIKE '2013-12-01 00:00:00';

Comment: @Staggen . . . If you want to get other fields, then that is another question.  I would suggest you ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is not the best answer but, you just need to put another condition and it is done.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  player_id
FROM login_history
WHERE (timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00')
       AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') - 1))
     OR (timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')
         AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00') - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be use the same table again with an alias

```
SELECT DISTINCT lh1.player_id 
FROM login_history lh1 join login_history lh2 on lh1.player_id  = lh2.player_id 
WHERE lh1.timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')-1) 
AND lh2.timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1);
```

If the number of rows is too high you can use subqueries

```
SELECT DISTINCT lh1.player_id 
FROM 
(Select distinct player_id from login_history 
WHERE lh1.timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00')-1) )lh1 
JOIN
(Select distinct player_id from login_history 
WHERE lh2.timestamp BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-02-01 00:00:00') 
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-03-01 00:00:00')-1) )lh2 on lh1.player_id  = lh2.player_id;
```

Hopes it helps.
Regards.